# Keras subclassing style model training huge performance difference

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, profile

I was running DSSM_N and DSSM on a dataset with batch size 512 on 2060.
However,
DSSM_N costs ~35ms per batch
DSSM.  costs ~400ms per batch.
What makes this huge performance difference? I have checked profiling which said
that DSSM costs ~350ms on All Others Time. How can I fix the DSSM implementation?
Many thanks in advance.

Edited as suggested by Micheal:
The main difference is DSSM makes a hash-table-like lookup (notice tf.nn.embedding_lookup and IntegerLookup) which makes the dataset preprocess a little bit simpler while in DSSM_N this lookup was done in dataset preprocess in advance. However, I don't believe this simple hash table like makes such a big difference. What was I doing wrong?

```
import pickle
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_text as text  # required for BERT hub model

from keras.layers import Layer, Embedding, Dense, Concatenate, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Dot, Hashing, TextVectorization, GRU, IntegerLookup
from keras import Model
import random

from ..config import *
from ..util import *


def embedding_sequence_reduce_mean(x, mask):
    # float[B,L,E], bool[B,L] -> float[B,E]
    x = tf.ragged.boolean_mask(x, mask)  # (B, Lr, E) remove masked data
    x = tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=1)  # (B, E)
    x = tf.where(tf.math.is_nan(x), 0.0, x)  # nan to 0
    return x


def embedding_masked_to_zero(x, mask):
    mask = tf.expand_dims(  # B -> B 1 align for broadcasting
        tf.cast(mask, dtype=tf.float32), axis=1)
    return x * mask


USER_ID_DIM = 128
MEDIA_ID_DIM = 64
GENRE_DIM = 32
ORIGIN_DIM = 32
LATENT_DIM = latent_dim
N_HASH = 8
N_BIN = 1024

print('N_HASH', N_HASH)
print('N_BIN', N_BIN)


class HashEmbedding(Layer):
    # TODO: with_importance is not supported
    def __init__(
        self, n_hash, n_bin, output_dim,
        embeddings_initializer='uniform', embeddings_regularizer=None,
        activity_regularizer=None, embeddings_constraint=None,
        mask_zero=False, input_length=None, **kwargs
    ):
        super(HashEmbedding, self).__init__()
        self.mask_zero = mask_zero
        self.n_hash = n_hash
        self.n_bin = n_bin
        # salts no duplication
        self.salts = random.sample(range(self.n_hash * 32), self.n_hash)
        self.hashs = [Hashing(
            num_bins=self.n_bin,
            # if mask_zero then hash 0 to 0
            mask_value=(0 if self.mask_zero else None),
            salt=self.salts[i])
            for i in range(self.n_hash)]
        self.embedding = Embedding(
            self.n_bin, output_dim,
            embeddings_initializer=embeddings_initializer,
            embeddings_regularizer=embeddings_regularizer,
            activity_regularizer=activity_regularizer,
            embeddings_constraint=embeddings_constraint,
            mask_zero=mask_zero, input_length=input_length
        )

    def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
        if not self.mask_zero:
            return None
        return tf.not_equal(inputs, 0)

    def call(self, inputs):
        shape = inputs.shape
        hash = tf.stack([hash(inputs)  # [I], n_hash
                        for hash in self.hashs], axis=len(shape))
        x = self.embedding(hash)  # [I], n_hash, emb_dim
        x = tf.reduce_sum(x, axis=len(shape))  # [I], emb_dim
        return x


class StringVectorization(Layer):
    def __init__(self, vocab, embedding_dim=32, output_dim=16):
        super(StringVectorization, self).__init__()
        self.text_vectorization = TextVectorization(
            vocabulary=vocab, split='character')
        self.embedding = Embedding(
            self.text_vectorization.vocabulary_size(), embedding_dim, mask_zero=True)
        self.gru = GRU(output_dim)

    def call(self, inputs):  # B, S
        x = self.text_vectorization(inputs)
        x = self.embedding(x)
        return self.gru(x)


class TfBertZh(Layer):  # 128 - 2 input length limit
    def __init__(self):  # output_dim 768
        super(TfBertZh, self).__init__()
        self.preprocess = hub.KerasLayer(
            zh_preprocessor_model_file, trainable=False)
        self.encoder = hub.KerasLayer(zh_encoder_model_file, trainable=False)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.preprocess(inputs)
        x = self.encoder(x)['pooled_output']
        return x


class DNN(Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DNN, self).__init__()
        self.concat = Concatenate(axis=1)
        self.dense1 = Dense(64)
        self.bn = BatchNormalization()
        self.drop = Dropout(0.1)
        self.dense2 = Dense(32)

    def call(self, inputs: list):
        from keras.activations import tanh
        x = self.concat(inputs)
        x = self.drop(tanh(self.bn(self.dense1(x))))
        x = tanh(self.dense2(x))
        return x


with open(stats_file_pkl, 'rb') as f:
    sinfo = pickle.load(f)
with open(vocab_file_pkl, 'rb') as f:
    vocab = pickle.load(f)


class DSSM_N(Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(DSSM_N, self).__init__()
        self.user_id = HashEmbedding(
            N_HASH, N_BIN, USER_ID_DIM, mask_zero=True)
        self.item_id = Embedding(
            sinfo['media_id']['unique'], MEDIA_ID_DIM, mask_zero=True)
        self.genre = Embedding(
            sinfo['genre_id']['unique'], GENRE_DIM, mask_zero=True)
        self.origin = Embedding(
            sinfo['origin_id']['unique'], ORIGIN_DIM, mask_zero=True)
        self.user_dnn = DNN()
        self.item_dnn = DNN()
        self.dot = Dot(axes=1, normalize=False)

    def call(self, inputs):
        u = self.compute_user_latent({'id': inputs['user']})
        n_pos = inputs['pos'].shape[1]
        n_neg = inputs['neg'].shape[1]
        ui_pos = []
        ui_neg = []

        def signal(u, i):
            return tf.exp(self.dot([u, i]))

        for j in range(n_pos):
            i = self.compute_item_latent({
                'id': inputs['pos'][:, j],
                'genre': inputs['pos_genre'][:, j, :],  # B N 4
                'origin': inputs['pos_origin'][:, j, :]  # B N 2
            })
            ui_pos.append(signal(u, i))
        ui_pos = tf.add_n(ui_pos)
        for j in range(n_neg):
            i = self.compute_item_latent({
                'id': inputs['neg'][:, j],
                'genre': inputs['neg_genre'][:, j, :],
                'origin': inputs['neg_origin'][:, j, :]
            })
            ui_neg.append(signal(u, i))
        ui_neg = tf.add_n(ui_neg)
        return tf.squeeze(ui_pos / (ui_pos + ui_neg))

    def compute_user_latent(self, inputs):
        id = self.user_id(inputs['id'])
        latent = self.user_dnn([id])
        return latent

    def compute_item_latent(self, inputs):
        id = self.item_id(inputs['id'])
        genre = self.genre(inputs['genre'])  # B 4 -> B 4 E
        genre = embedding_sequence_reduce_mean(genre, genre._keras_mask)
        origin = self.origin(inputs['origin'])  # B 2 -> B 2 E
        origin = embedding_sequence_reduce_mean(origin, origin._keras_mask)
        latent = self.item_dnn([id, genre, origin])
        return latent


user_df = pd.read_pickle(preprocessed_user_file_pkl)
media_df = pd.read_pickle(preprocessed_media_file_pkl)
genre_df = pd.read_pickle(clean_genre_file_pkl)
origin_df = pd.read_pickle(clean_origin_file_pkl)


class MediaPreprocess(Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MediaPreprocess, self).__init__()
        self.lookup = IntegerLookup(vocabulary=list(media_df['id']))
        self.genre_table = tf.Variable(
            [[0] * 4] + list(media_df['genre']), dtype=tf.int32, trainable=False)
        self.origin_table = tf.Variable(
            [[0] * 2] + list(media_df['origin']), dtype=tf.int32, trainable=False)
        self.id_embedding = Embedding(
            self.lookup.vocabulary_size() + 1, MEDIA_ID_DIM, mask_zero=True)
        self.genre_embedding =\
            Embedding(genre_df['id'].max() + 1, GENRE_DIM, mask_zero=True)
        self.origin_embedding =\
            Embedding(origin_df['id'].max() + 1, ORIGIN_DIM, mask_zero=True)

    def __call__(self, inputs):
        index = self.lookup(inputs)  # B -> B

        vector = self.id_embedding(index)  # B -> B E
        vector = embedding_masked_to_zero(vector, vector._keras_mask)

        genre = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.genre_table, index)
        genre = self.genre_embedding(genre)
        genre = embedding_sequence_reduce_mean(genre, genre._keras_mask)

        origin = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.origin_table, index)
        origin = self.origin_embedding(origin)
        origin = embedding_sequence_reduce_mean(origin, origin._keras_mask)

        return {
            'id': vector,
            'genre': genre,
            'origin': origin}


class UserPreprocess(Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UserPreprocess, self).__init__()
        self.lookup = IntegerLookup(vocabulary=list(user_df['id']))
        self.embedding = HashEmbedding(
            N_HASH, N_BIN, USER_ID_DIM, mask_zero=True)

    def __call__(self, inputs):
        vector = self.embedding(inputs)
        vector = embedding_masked_to_zero(vector, vector._keras_mask)

        return {'id': vector}


class DSSM(Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DSSM, self).__init__()
        self.user_pp = UserPreprocess()
        self.item_pp = MediaPreprocess()

        self.user_nn = DNN()
        self.item_nn = DNN()
        dot = Dot(axes=1, normalize=False)
        self.signal = lambda u, i: tf.exp(dot([u, i]))

    def call(self, inputs):
        user = inputs['user']  # B
        pos_s = inputs['pos']  # B N_POS=1
        neg_s = inputs['neg']  # B N_NEG=7
        n_pos = pos_s.shape[1]
        n_neg = neg_s.shape[1]

        u = self.user_pp(user)['id']  # B E(uid)
        u = self.user_nn([u])  # B L

        def compute_ui(i_s, count):
            ui = []
            for j in range(count):
                i = self.item_pp(i_s[:, j])
                i = self.item_nn([i['id'], i['genre'], i['origin']])
                ui.append(self.signal(u, i))
            return tf.add_n(ui)  # C B 1 -> B 1

        pos_ui = compute_ui(pos_s, n_pos)  # B 1
        neg_ui = compute_ui(neg_s, n_neg)  # B 1
        return tf.squeeze(pos_ui / (neg_ui + pos_ui))  # B
```

Comment: The main difference is DSSM makes a hash-table-like lookup (notice tf.nn.embedding_lookup and IntegerLookup) which makes the dataset preprocess a little bit simpler while in DSSM_N this lookup was done in dataset preprocess in advance. However, I don't believe this simple hash table like makes such a big difference. What was I doing wrong?

Comment: Your comment should be placed in your question as an edit